# Bootstrap dropdown is always behind a sticky element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, sticky

I'am using bootstrap dropdown menu and https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill to fix some elements on the top of the screen. See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nagyt234/tuf9pwhf/18/).

I could not achieve, that the dropdown menu appers over the "sticky line". I've tried with z-index wothout success.

Instead of stickyfill I've tried with other sticky plugins ([makefixed.js](https://github.com/guimadaleno/makefixed.js/tree/master), [jquery.sticky.js](https://github.com/garand/sticky)) but the result is the same. The menu is always behind the sticky element.

Any idea?

The HTML code (the same as on jsfiddle):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".sticky").Stickyfill();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.diet-health.info/js/stickyfill.js"></script>

<header class="sticky" style="padding:3px;top:0px">
  <div class="dropdown btn-group" style="float:right;">
    <button id="right-menu" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Right Menu</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" aria-labelledby="right-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<p>Normal line</p>
<p>Normal line</p>
<p>Normal line</p>
<div class="sticky" style="top:40px">
  <p>
********************************************* A sticky line *********************************************
  </p>
</div>
<p>Normal line</p>
<p>Normal line</p>
<p>Normal line</p>
<p>Normal line</p>
<p>Normal line</p>
<p>Normal line</p>
<p>Normal line</p>
<p>Normal line</p>
<p>Normal line</p>
<p>Normal line</p>
<p>Normal line</p>
<p>Normal line</p>
<p>Normal line</p>
<p>Normal line</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `z-index` in `header`

```
header.sticky {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

working jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/tuf9pwhf/22/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Check demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tuf9pwhf/19/)

HTML:

```
<div class="sticky" style="top:40px; z-index: -1;">
  <p>
********************************************* A sticky line *********************************************
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply z-index

```
.sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the class of header **sticky** to another it's affecting the child html element